# Android: How to keep you app active after user grants permission?

Tags: android, permissions

I am struggling with a small problem. I am very new to the Android app development so please excuse my question if it looks silly.

When I launch my app then I ask for a permission to be granted by user, at this time I get a dialog for requesting permission on top of my app. But, when I grant access to the permission by pressing "Allow" then my app goes in background and then I have to relaunch my app.

I want to know what is the right way to return the focus to my app after user grants the permission by pressing the "Allow" button so that I do not have to relaunch the app again manually?

My code for asking permission is as below:

```
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        Log.e("Camera", "Permission to READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not granted, let's ask user");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }else {
        Log.e("Camera", "Permission to READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is already granted, let's find out pictures");
        File CameraDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath());
// Going to get no of pictures available in the DCIM directory.
        get_no_of_pictures(CameraDirectory);
    }
    Log.e("uEarn.Camera", "Finishing the CameraPhotos app");
    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: You have finish() in your code, this why your activity finishing.
Don't forget to override onRequestPermissionsResult method in activity, so you know if user allowed permissions or not.

Comment: The finish() statement  at the end of your code closes your activity. Remove it, and it'll stay there.

Comment: Thanks, Alex and Kunal. It indeed worked in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just should remove `finish();`, it will stay in same page.

But you can do more in onRequestPermissionsResult like this below.

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (permissions != null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
                    if (Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.equalsIgnoreCase(permissions[i])
                            && (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                        File CameraDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath());
// Going to get no of pictures available in the DCIM directory.
                        get_no_of_pictures(CameraDirectory);

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi!

Thanks for your suggestion. I will make use of this function. One more question about requestCode, where I can find the requestCode for permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. I have seen in some examples to be passed as 1 but is there requestCode for each permission or is it required to be passed as 1?

Thanks